# I found this error ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

the shape of my X_train is
array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

```
   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   ...,

   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

```
while shape of my y_train is 

array([1, 2, 1, ..., 2, 1, 1])

How can i solve this question. Please solve my this issue
```

Comment: Is your x_train 3 dimensional, or just a list with a single two-dimensional element?

If the latter, try with said element, otherwise you may need to reshape your array.

More information about the specific function you are calling would also be helpful.

Comment: I ahve reshaped X_train but still giving error. I send you my code Please correct it